# Results returning twice from MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm struggling to figure out why my results are returning twice for the group messages. It's returning the correct values for the single conversations.

It should be returning all the data from `Data in table` screenshot. However it's returning the data with `is_group = 1` twice.

Data in Table:

[image]

MySQL Query:

```
(SELECT dm.* FROM `direct_message`AS dm 
 INNER JOIN direct_message_thread AS dmt    
 ON dmt.chat_id = dm.id 
 WHERE 
 ( dm.recipient_id = '10896' OR dm.creator_id = '10896' ) 
 AND dm.school_id = '1' 
 GROUP BY dm.id 
 ORDER BY dmt.inserted DESC 
) UNION ALL ( 
    SELECT dm.* FROM `direct_message` AS dm 
    INNER JOIN direct_message_thread AS dmt ON dmt.chat_id = dm.id 
    LEFT JOIN direct_message_group AS dmg ON dmg.chat_id = dm.id 
    WHERE dmg.staff_id = '10896' AND dm.school_id = '1' 
    GROUP BY dm.id 
    ORDER BY dmt.inserted DESC
) LIMIT 0, 25
```

Results:

[image]

I think it could be because of the first `SELECT` getting the results and then the `UNION ALL` get the same results but not grouping together with the first `SELECT`

When I try and do the following:

```
(SELECT dm.* FROM `direct_message`AS dm 
 INNER JOIN direct_message_thread AS dmt    
 ON dmt.chat_id = dm.id 
 WHERE ( dm.recipient_id = '10896' OR dm.creator_id = '10896' ) 
 AND dm.school_id = '1' 
) UNION ALL ( 
    SELECT dm.* FROM `direct_message` AS dm 
    INNER JOIN direct_message_thread AS dmt ON dmt.chat_id = dm.id 
    LEFT JOIN direct_message_group AS dmg ON dmg.chat_id = dm.id 
    WHERE dmg.staff_id = '10896' AND dm.school_id = '1' 
) 
GROUP BY dm.id 
ORDER BY dmt.inserted DESC
LIMIT 0, 25
```

It shows this error message:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'GROUP BY dm.id  ORDER BY dmt.inserted DESC LIMIT 0, 25' at line
>   14

Answer (score 0):

You are using union for two queries.
Records 595-597 and 599-601 are met both of them.

My be better to select to whole query with

```
select id,...
    from (...)
group by id
```

Comment: Could you show me an example based on my code above?

Comment: select dm.id,dmt.inserted,...  from ((SELECT dm.* FROM `direct_message`AS dm 
 INNER JOIN direct_message_thread AS dmt    
 ON dmt.chat_id = dm.id 
 WHERE ( dm.recipient_id = '10896' OR dm.creator_id = '10896' ) 
 AND dm.school_id = '1' 
) UNION ALL ( 
    SELECT dm.* FROM `direct_message` AS dm 
    INNER JOIN direct_message_thread AS dmt ON dmt.chat_id = dm.id 
    LEFT JOIN direct_message_group AS dmg ON dmg.chat_id = dm.id 
    WHERE dmg.staff_id = '10896' AND dm.school_id = '1' 
) )
GROUP BY dm.id 
ORDER BY dmt.inserted DESC
LIMIT 0, 25